# Concept of multiple "virtual screens" for a single physical screen

Tags: xmonad, xmonad-contrib

I use XMonad with a single physical screen with 10 workspaces. I would like to have two or more separate instances of worksapces, kinda like multiple "virtual screens" on a single physical screen. E.g., virtual screen 1 and 2 should each independently have their own workspaces and I would then use some key-bindings to switch between the virtual screens.

How can I achieve the desired configuration? I stumbled upon [XMonad.Layout.IndependentScreens](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/xmonad-contrib-0.17.0/docs/XMonad-Layout-IndependentScreens.html) but it does not really cover what I need.

Comment: How does it not cover that? Sounds like it's exactly what you need, just that your virtual screen won't be "attached" to another monitor output. Potentially you just need to figure out some code to switch the current "virtual screen" for the monitor output.